# How to test that <Navigate /> will navigate app to correct component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library, testing-library

I use `react-router-dom v6`

Routing component.

```
if (!loaded) {
 return <Spiner/>;
}
return <Routes>
    <Route 
      path="/login"
      element={
       <Public>
        <Suspense fallback={...}>
          <LoginComponent />
        </Suspense>
       </Public>
      }
    />
    <Route 
      path="/protected"
      element={
       <Private>
        <Suspense fallback={...}>
         <Protected />
       </Suspense>
       </Private>
      }
    />
</Routes>
```

Private wrapper

```
const Private = ({children}) => {
   const {state} = useLocation();
   const {loggedIn} = useAuthHook();
   if (!loggedIn) {
      return <Navigate to="/login" state={state}/>
   }
   return children;
}
```

So, what I'm trying to do.

I try to test, that application will navigate to `<LoginComponent/>` if user is not loggedIn.

```
test.each([{route: "/protected"}])
("will render login page if user is not loggedIn", async ({route}) => { 
   const {getByText, history} = render(<RoutingContainer />, 
      {routeHistory: [route], 
      preloadedState: preloadedStateWithFalseLoggedIn
   })
   await waitFor(() => expect(getByText(/Sign in/i)).toBeInTheDocument());
   expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/login");
})
```

[image]

[image]

In the terminal we can see that I received empty div.
If I remove line with `await waitFor(...)` the test will pass.
I guess that thing is with `<Navigate />`.
How can I test component that will be rendered after use `<Navigate/>`?

**UPDATED**

I use `Routing` component inside `RoutingContainer`

```
const RoutingContainer = () => {
  const {checkedWho} = useSelector(state => state.login);

  useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(whoAmIRequest());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Routing loaded={checkedWho}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: did you manage to test this? I'm trying to test the same scenario

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot `screen` and put the text in quotes. And I always use a timeout for async assertions.

```
await waitFor(()=>expect(screen.getByText('Sign in')).toBeInTheDocument(),{timeout: 5000})
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Thank you

Comment: got any errors?

Comment: Yes. Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test. I added ```jest.setTimeout(5000)``` before ```test.each...``` but it didn't help. Without ```timeout``` I received the same error with ```waitFor```.